# Create a struct name with a given string in C language

Tags: c, string, struct, visual-studio-code, scanf

I want to create a code that does something like this:

```
typedef struct {
  char name[1024];
  int age;
  char gender;
}person;

person Jacob = {.name = "Jacob", .age = 15, .gender = 'M'};
```

But I need to use the scanf option to get the variables, something like this:

```
typedef struct {
   char name[1024];
   int age;
   char gender;
}person;

char name_person[1024];
int age_person;
char gender_person;
scanf(" [:^\n],%d,%c",name_person,&age_person,&gender_person);
```

I would know if I can do something like this:

```
person name_person = {.name = name_person, .age = age_person, .gender = gender_person};
```

To do the same thing as the code above? I'm sorry if it sounds like a stupid question, I'm very new to C language.

Answer (score 0):

For name you need to use c builtin func to make copies... the other field of your struct can be assigned straightforward

Answer (score 0):

You can use scanf with struct like this.

```
typedef struct {
   char name[1024];
   int age;
   int sex;
}person;

person human;
scanf(" [:^\n],%d,%c",human.name,&human.age,&human.sex);
```

or you can use struct like this

```
person human;
char c;
int a;
float b;

scanf("%c %d %f",&c,&a,&b);

human.name=c;
human.age=a;
human.sex=b;
```

Comment: But if I wanted to store that in a hash table, that would always be the same thing?

Comment: I edited answer, maybe it help, But there is no simple hash table cod in c, you can check [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/data_structures_algorithms/hash_table_program_in_c.htm)

Answer (score 0):

When using 'scanf' you need to match the format to the variable.

The `scanf` will deal with the name (char []), and age (int), but you will temporary variable to handle the conversion of the 'sex' attribute from char to int.

Also consider change to format - looks like the input is comma separated. If this is the case then'%[^,]' will work.

```
{
        // Good idea to initialize 'p'.
        person p = {} ;
        char sex ;

        scanf(" %[^,],%d,%c", p.name, &p.age, &sex) ;
        p.sex = sex ;
}
```